# Memory leak in c++ python wrapper

Tags: python, c++, boost, memory-leaks, shared-libraries

I'm develloping the backend of an app and I try to wrap my c++ code in python. I've used Boost Python3 to link c++ to python. I'm able to get a shared library and call it from python. For the moment, everything is working.

The problem arises when I'm trying to export this library. I would like to be able to use it from another location or computer without recompiling the c++ code.

To try this library, I'm just moving the library in another folder with its depedencies and check with `ldd` if all the depedencies are resolved (no problem for that).

Then, I'm trying to call some object from python3. At the beginning, I'm able to run many functions, but if I quit and relaunch python3, I start to have some segmentation fault, memory corruption, ... As an example: *** Error in `python3': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001ebeb50 ***

I've tried to use valgrind to find any memory leaks. My program in c++ doesn't have any memory leak. When I try valgrind with my python code, I don't have any leaks for the library located in its original folder. However, after having moved the library, I start to have some leaks as:

`Invalid write of size 4
==22695==    at 0x6DCA0F9: Test::Test(std::string, std::string, std::string, int) (maintests.cpp:71)
==22695==    by 0x6933E5B: boost::python::objects::value_holder<Test>::value_holder(_object*) (value_holder.hpp:137)
==22695==    by 0x6934D8D: boost::python::objects::make_holder<0>::apply<boost::python::objects::value_holder<ritmo::Test>, boost::mpl::joint_view<boost::python::detail::drop1<boost::python::detail::type_list<boost::python::optional<std::string, std::string, std::string, int, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_>, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_> >, boost::python::optional<std::string, std::string, std::string, int, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_, mpl_::void_> > >::execute(_object*) (make_holder.hpp:94)
==22695==    by 0x693924E: _object* boost::python::detail::invoke<int, void (*)(_object*), boost::python::arg_from_python<_object*> >(boost::python::detail::invoke_tag_<true, false>, int const&, void (*&)(_object*), boost::python::arg_from_python<_object*>&) (invoke.hpp:81)
==22695==    by 0x6936942: boost::python::detail::caller_arity<1u>::impl<void (*)(_object*), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<void, _object*> >::operator()(_object*, _object*) (caller.hpp:223)
==22695==    by 0x6935D88: boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<boost::python::detail::caller<void (*)(_object*), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<void, _object*> > >::operator()(_object*, _object*) (py_function.hpp:38)
==22695==    by 0x71CE139: boost::python::objects::function::call(_object*, _object*) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0)
==22695==    by 0x71CE4A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0)
==22695==    by 0x71D8742: boost::python::handle_exception_impl(boost::function0<void>) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0)
==22695==    by 0x71CCDB2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0)
==22695==    by 0x53493C: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==22695==    by 0x4F14F9: PyObject_Call (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==22695==  Address 0x6333fe0 is 16 bytes after a block of size 32 in arena "client"`

I'm struggling with this issue. Any idea or tips will be more than welcome.

Thank you

Comment: You must provide a small self-contained sample - a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error with a small example ... Any advice ?

Comment: Use a debugger. See where the memory corruption happens. Don't settle for a workaround you don't even understand.

Comment: I've compiled my program with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and I've found one error with some vector copy based on iterators. I think I have solved a part of the problem, but I still have a segfault at the end. I'm currently checking if I'm not deleting twice an object

Comment: I don't think anymore that the issue is coming from the python wrapper, but from my shared library. From what I've understood, a shared library is managing is own stack in the memory, so when I was compiling all at once, I had only one stack, but now that I'm using the shared library, I have at least two stacks (one for the executable and one for the shared library)

Comment: @tambre, thank you for the advice, but gdb doesn't find anything without `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. With this flag, I still have a segfault at the end and nothing in gdb :(

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the segfault.
The header I was using for compiling the program was different from the one used by the library. One class member was not declared and so no memory was allocated to this member.